# Searching for a filename in a folder

Tags: python

I have a list of ts files inside a folder. I try to extract the content id from the XML which is the filename without extension. I need to search for a ts file that matches the content id. For some reason, it's failing. I am attaching the code below. I am also attaching the screenshot for the ts files.

```
import glob
import lxml.etree as et
import os, csv


ASSET_METADATA_PATH = '/Users/roradhak/eVision/failed_assets/'
TS_PATH = '/Users/roradhak/eVision/ts_check/'

def parse_file(path):

    tree = et.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    trailer_id = ""
    programs = root.xpath('Program[@title="Program"]')
    if len(programs) == 0:
        return None, None, None
    program = programs[0] # TODO - Are multiple programs expected? If so, the function should return a list of tuples
# Get the Content ID
    c_id = program.xpath('props/*[@title="Content ID"]')
    if len(c_id) == 0:
        content_id = None
    else:
        content_id = c_id[0].text
    # Get the has_trailer attribute
    has_t = program.xpath('props/*[@title="Has_Trailer"]')
    has_trailer = has_t[0].text
    if has_t[0].text =="Y":
        trailer_id = content_id.replace('M','T',1)
    # Get the content name
    n = program.xpath('props/*[@title="Name"]')
    if len(n) == 0:
        content_name = None
    else:
        content_name = n[0].text
    return content_id, content_name, has_trailer, trailer_id

def main():
    asset_metadata = glob.glob(os.path.join(ASSET_METADATA_PATH, u'*.xml'))
    movies = glob.glob(os.path.join(TS_PATH, u'*.ts'))

    for p in asset_metadata:
        print(u'Processing: {p}'.format(p=p).encode('utf-8'))
        print content_id, content_name, has_trailer, trailer_id
        content_id, content_name, has_trailer, trailer_id= parse_file(p)
        if u'{c}.ts'.format(c=content_id) not in TS_PATH:
            print "No Movie"
        if has_trailer =="Y":
            if u'{c}.ts'.format(c=trailer_id) not in movies:
                print "No trailer"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output as below**

[image]

```
/Users/roradhak/IVPGET_Local/venv/bin/python /Users/roradhak/Downloads/validate_xml.py
Processing: /Users/roradhak/eVision/failed_assets/E30000001557115265_2019_08_29T11_20_08Z.xml
MD009232 Ep 143 - Cool look Hair style N 
No Movie
Processing: /Users/roradhak/eVision/failed_assets/10000000717960000_2019_10_09T15_04_20Z.xml
MZ008931 Aan: Men At Work Y TZ008931
No Movie
No trailer
Processing: /Users/roradhak/eVision/failed_assets/E30000001557537308_2019_08_09T19_15_22Z.xml
MZ010564 EP29 - Episode 29 - Raheem S1 Y TZ010564
No Movie
No trailer

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What Python version are you using? If you are on Python 3.4 or newer, [```pathlib```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) will make your life a lot easier when dealing with paths and files.

Comment: python 2.7. Since thats in my environment. But i reckon the search is not related to any version

Comment: Not related but you probably need to return one more ```None``` here ```return None, None, None```, in ```parse_file()```.

Comment: @accdias Agree. I just changed the code to like this. But still its not finding from the second file.

            if Path(TS_PATH + '{c}.ts'.format(c=content_id)).exists():
                print "Movie:Yes"
            if has_trailer =="Y":
                if Path(TS_PATH + '{c}.ts'.format(c=trailer_id)).exists():
                    print "Trailer:Yes"

Comment: I guess it is not working because ```glob.glob()``` returns a list with full paths and, if I got it right from your code, you are only testing for the presence of the ```filename.ts``` in the list. I'm more used to ```pathlib``` though and I could help you more if that was the case. The code would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @accdias Yes. Please. That will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and Python 3.4+:

```
from pathlib import Path

failed_assets_folder = Path('/Users/roradhak/eVision/failed_assets')
ts_folder = Path('/Users/roradhak/eVision/ts_check')


def main():
    for failed_asset in failed_assets_folder.glob('*.xml'):
        print(f'Processing: {failed_asset.name}')

        content_id, content_name, has_trailer, trailer_id = parse_file(failed_asset.name)
        print(f'{content_id}, {content_name}, {has_trailer}, {trailer_id}')

        if not Path(ts_folder / f'{content_id}.ts').exists():
            print('No Movie')

        if has_trailer == 'Y':
            if not Path(ts_folder / f'{trailer_id}.ts').exists():
                print('No trailer')
```

It just implements the file search portion and it is not tested though.

Comment: Since i am running python 2.7, "f" is not supported. How do i change it to be used in 2.7?

Comment: Do you have ```pathlib``` available for Python 2.7? You can substitute those ```f-strings``` with your usual ```format()``` ones. But, as you can see, with Python 3.4+ and ```f-strings```, the code looks cleaner and more readable. Please, consider migrating to Python 3 as soon as possible. Python 2 will reach end of life on January 1st 2020.

Comment: Yeah. Will upgrade the version soon . But its very urgent for me to get this worked today. Here is the changed code but still issues. Yes, i have pathlib in 2.7. not sure how to use it in 2.7. Here is the code.
        if not Path(movies / '{content_id}.ts').exists():
            print('No Movie')

Comment: Change ```Path(movies / '{content_id}.ts').exists():``` into ```Path(movies / '{0}.ts'.format(content_id)).exists():```  and see if that do the trick.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'str'. This is what i am getting

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for helping. I am trying to get a working solution in 2.7

Comment: Isn't ```movies``` a list you are filling with ```glob()```? The example I posted is for ```Path``` objects. Check the answer again and try to get how it works. It is the best I can do for now. Also, take a look at [Idiomatic Python pathlib vs. os.path](https://www.scivision.dev/python-idiomatic-pathlib-use/), where the author compares ```os.path``` and ```pathlib```.